Under what conditions on the set cost function are optimal k-partitions nested?
Given a set $S$ (assumed finite), a $k$-partition $P$ is a collection of $k$ disjoint subsets $S_1 \dots S_k$ whose union is $S$. Let $C$ be a function quantifying the cost of a partition, and having the following form
$$
C(P) = \sum_{i=1}^k c(S_i).
$$
That is, $c$ gives the cost of each of the partition's subsets, and the total cost of the partition is found by adding up the costs of all of its subsets. For clarity, we call $C$ the partition cost function and $c$ the set cost function. Assume that $c(\emptyset)=0$. We say that $P$ is an optimal $k$-partition if for any $k$-partition $P'$, we have $C(P) \leq C(P')$. A subset $S_i$ of a $k$-partition is allowed to be empty, and it therefore follows that if $m >n$ then an optimal $m$-partition cannot have a cost exceeding that of an optimal $n$-partition.
Now suppose that for a given set $S$ and cost function $c$, we have an optimal $k$-partition $P^*_k$ and an optimal $k+1$-partition $P^*_{k+1}$. Under what conditions on the set cost function $c$ is it guaranteed that $P^*_{k+1}$ is a refinement of $P^*_k$? That is, when is it guaranteed that a subset of $P^*_{k+1}$ intersects with at most one subset of $P^*_k$? Similarly: under what conditions is it guaranteed that for any optimal $k$-partition, there exists some optimal $k+1$-partition that is a refinement it? The assumption that $c(\emptyset)=0$ could be discarded if it is helpful.
